# Why is this returning a NoneType?

Tags: python, wikipedia, attributeerror, nonetype

I'm trying to scrape info off of Wikipedia using the function below, but I'm running into an **Attribute Error** because a function call is returning **None**. Can someone please try and explain why this is returning None?

```
import wikipedia as wp
import string

def add_section_info(search):
    HTML = wp.page(search).html().encode("UTF-8") #gets HTML source from Wikipedia

    with open("temp.xml",'w') as t: #write HTML to xml format
        t.write(HTML)

    table_of_contents = []
    dict_of_section_info = {}

    #This extracts the info in the table of contents
    with open("temp.xml",'r') as r:
        for line in r:
            if "toclevel" in line: 
                new_string = line.partition("#")[2]
                content_title = new_string.partition("\"")[0]
                tbl = string.maketrans("_"," ")
                content_title = content_title.translate(tbl)
                table_of_contents.append(content_title)

    print wp.page(search).section("Aortic rupture") #this is None, but shouldn't be

    for item in table_of_contents:
        section = wp.page(search).section(item).encode("UTF-8")
        print section
        if section == "":
            continue
        else:
            dict_of_section_info[item] = section

    with open("Section_Info.txt",'a') as sect:
        sect.write(search)
        sect.write("------------------------------------------\n")
        for item in dict_of_section_info:
            sect.write(item)
            sect.write("\n\n")
            sect.write(dict_of_section_info[item])
        sect.write("####################################\n\n")

add_section_info("Abdominal aortic aneurysm")
```

What I don't understand is that if I run `add_section_info("HIV")`, for example, it works perfectly.

The source code for the imported wikipedia is [here](https://github.com/goldsmith/Wikipedia/blob/master/wikipedia/wikipedia.py)

My output on the above code is this:

```
Abdominal aortic aneurysm

Signs and symptoms
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pharoslabsllc/Documents/wikitest.py", line 79, in <module>
add_section_info(line)
  File "/home/pharoslabsllc/Documents/wikitest.py", line 30, in add_section_info
    section = wp.page(search).section(item).encode("UTF-8")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Comment: Can you tell us where this error occurs? Just add the traceback to the question.

Comment: Try to `print(repr(item))` inside the loop that fails.

Comment: You've got a value hard-coded there.  What happens if instead of `print wp.page(search).section("Aortic rupture")` you did `print wp.page(search).section(item)`?

Comment: If I print, inside the for-loop, `wp.page(search).section(item)`, I get `None`. That's the part I don't understand - it should be the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `page` method never returns `None` (you can easily check this in the source code), however the `section` method *does* return `None` if the title cannot be found. See the [documentation](https://wikipedia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/code.html#wikipedia.WikipediaPage.section):

> **`section(section_title)`**
>
> Get the plain text content of a section from `self.sections`.
>   **Returns `None` if `section_title` isn’t found**, otherwise returns a whitespace stripped string.

So the answer is that the wikipedia page you are referring to has no section titled `Aortic rupture`, *as far as the library is concerned*.

Looking at wikipedia itself it seems like the page [Abdominal aortic aneurysm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abdominal_aortic_aneurysm#Aortic_rupture) does have such a section.

Note that if you try to check what the value of `wp.page(search).sections` is you get: `[]`. I.e. **it seems like the library isn't parsing the sections properly.**

---

From the source code of the library found [here](https://github.com/goldsmith/Wikipedia/blob/master/wikipedia/wikipedia.py#L653) you can see this test:

```
section = u"== {} ==".format(section_title)
try:
  index = self.content.index(section) + len(section)
except ValueError:
  return None
```

However:

```
In [14]: p.content.find('Aortic')
Out[14]: 3223

In [15]: p.content[3220:3220+50]
Out[15]: '== Aortic ruptureEdit ===\n\nThe signs and symptoms '
In [16]: p.section('Aortic ruptureEdit')
Out[16]: "The signs and symptoms of a ruptured AAA may includes severe pain in the lower back, flank, abdomen or groin. A mass that pulses with the heart beat may also be felt. The bleeding can leads to a hypovolemic shock with low blood pressure and a fast heart rate. This may lead to brief passing out.\nThe mortality of AAA rupture is up to 90%. 65–75% of patients die before they arrive at hospital and up to 90% die before they reach the operating room. The bleeding can be retroperitoneal or into the abdominal cavity. Rupture can also create a connection between the aorta and intestine or inferior vena cava. Flank ecchymosis (appearance of a bruise) is a sign of retroperitoneal bleeding, and is also called Grey Turner's sign.\nAortic aneurysm rupture may be mistaken for the pain of kidney stones, muscle related back pain."
```

Note the `Edit ==`. In other words the library has a bug that doesn't take into account the link to edit.

The same code works with the page for [HIV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HIV) because in that page the headings don't have an `edit` link right next to them. I have no idea why this is so, anywyay it looks like either a bug or a shortcoming of the library, so you should open a ticket on its issue tracker.

In the meanwhile you could use a simple fix like:

```
def find_section(page, title):
    res = page.section(title)
    if res is None:
        res = page.section(title + 'Edit')
    return res
```

and use this function instead of using the `.section` method. However this can only be a temporary fix.

Comment: Do you have any idea why running `add_section_info("HIV")` would work properly? Because even with "HIV", calling `wp.page(search).sections` returns `[ ]`, which is why I'm having to do this workaround.

Comment: @MIT_noob It's due to the `edit` link, see my last edit. If you check the `HIV` page most headings are missing that link and so the library works. However I'm not familiar with wikipedia and how they display stuff. I suggest you open a ticket in the library issue tracker, because this seems either a bug or a missing feature that isn't documented.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! 

Quick question: Can you explain what `p.content[3220:3220+50]` does?

Comment: @MIT the `i.content` is a string containing the text of the page. There I simply checked at which index the sites `Aortic`appeared, which happened to be `3223` and so I checked what the content was around that index using slicing. The `[3220:3220+50]` simply means take the characters from the `3220`th to the `3220+50`th one.

Answer (score 0):

`wp.page(search).section(item)` does not find the section you're looking for, and returns `None`. You don't check for it and try to handle the value as a string; this expectedly fails.